# cmake configure_file just for update a line not over-writing the whole file

Tags: cmake

I know that we can configure a file using cmake as discussed in [Can CMake generate configure file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8887117/can-cmake-generate-configure-file) for example.

My problem is that I want to **update** just one line of a file. For instance, assume that this line contains app version:

**my_header_version.h.in**:

```
#include "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/definitions.h"
```

**CMakeLists.txt**:

```
...
configure_file(my_header_version.h.in my_header_version.h)
...
```

**my_header_version.h**:

```
#include "/home/myusr/dev/src/definitions.h"
```

The problem is that if I change my_header_version.h into:

```
#include <some_lib.h>
#include "/home/myusr/dev/src/definitions.h"
```

and after that I run `cmake ..` command, then the line `#include <some_lib.h>` gets lost.
What should I do if I want to change my_header_version.h directly without changing my_header_version.h.in anytime?!

Comment: "What should I do if I want to change `my_header_version.h` directly without changing `my_header_version.h.in` anytime?!" - I know no such ready-to-use functionality in CMake. `configure_file` is intended to generate the **whole file**. If you want to "configure" only a *part* of the file, then move this part into a **separate header**, which could be generated with `configure_file`. This generated header could be included into the original one with standard `#include` directive.

Comment: @Tsyvarev you're right in this case and excuse me for my misunderstanding description; I updated the question

Comment: @Tsyvarev as u can c, my_header_version.h contains all include files; so may be it does not make sense to separate those `#include` statements

Comment: Oh, you want to modify the **generated** file **directly**. While it is possible to implement this semantic, it would be not such simple. Common approach is not to modify the *generated* file, but modify its *template* instead.

Comment: @Tsyvarev I don't want to change generated file; I just don't want to change .h.in file every time because it is not a part of source files directly

Comment: @Tsyvarev maybe separating template structures from non-template ones is a good approach as u said in your first comment! not sure!