# How can I include .sql file into c++ source?

Tags: c++, sqlpp11

I have a `.sql` file which defines the schema of tables, and I wish to include the same file as string with C++ source, and need to run the string to create those tables. I am using sqlpp11 with my C++ project. So any solution or lead could be more helpful for me.

**test.sql:**

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS t1 (
    c1 INT,
    c2 VARCHAR(10)
);
```

**testcpp.cpp:**
Need to include the file here and get the schema as string and then I need to run the string to create those tables at the run time.

I tried with `#define ASSTRING`, but getting this error "CREATE was not declared in this scope".

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26193554/9363996 if you decide to use cmake, you can use `configure_file` command to generate the header that contains the string. Or write a script of your own.

Comment: if you use gcc, you can also look into these answers https://stackoverflow.com/q/4864866/9363996

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the text on your sql file in something like STR():

**test.sql:**

```
STR(
  CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS t1 (
      c1 INT,
      c2 VARCHAR(10)
  );
)
```

and then in your c++ file you can expand the sql using a macro

```
#include <iostream>

#define STR(x) #x

const std::string sql =
#include "test.sql"
;

int main() { std::cout << sql << std::endl; }
```

Comment: Note that this collapses newlines to spaces. Also, the SQL string must still be lexically valid C++, so you must have (for example) an even number of quotation marks on each line, proper backslash sequences, and you can't have characters in the SQL like €.

Comment: Thanks for the response @JustCris , I tried the same like below:
#define STR(x)

const std::string sqldata =
#include "test.sql"
; // getting error here: expected primary-expression before ';' token

Comment: For the primary-expression problem you have to put the #include "test.sql" in a separated line without anything before and after like in my example

Comment: hi @JustCris, yes I did the same like you mentioned in your comment, but when I copy pasted the same here, then it went without new line.

Comment: And another thing is, I can't change the test.sql file like you mentioned (use STR inside .sql file), because I am using the same file somewhere else in my project (with cmake files). So, how can do the same without editing the .sql file?

Comment: I don't know if there is a better method but I would add a custom target in the cmake wich runs a bash script. The bash script reads the content of the sql file and write it in a c++ header file that can be included in your project

Answer (score 0):

I found this one as a useful solution:

```
function(make_includable input_file output_file)
    file(READ ${input_file} content)
    set(delim "for_c++_include")
    set(content "R\"${delim}(\n${content})${delim}\"")
    file(WRITE ${output_file} "${content}")
endfunction(make_includable)
```

## Use like

```
make_includable(external/shaders/cool.frag generated/cool.frag)
```

Then include in c++ like this:

```
constexpr char *test =
#include "generated/cool.frag"
;
```

but I need tried with sqlite3 for running the schema, and it is working.. so how can I run the schema with sqlpp11?

Comment: If you have another question, ask another question. SO works differently from discussion forums. Take a minute to take the [tour] so you can get the most out of this site.